# jQuery fetch jpeg image from IPCam

Tags: jquery, ajax, ip-camera

As a beginner in jQuery I followed the tutorial at jQuery For Designers (J4D) as Rzetterberg has told to check it out in this post [webcam image refresh with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5883271/1147571).

The images I am getting from my local IPCamera are shown correctly but after each time the function reloads the new fetched image will be placed below the previous fetched image. As a result of this I get a page in which each fetched images are placed below each other.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    url = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx?randval=';
            var randval = Math.random();
            var img = new Image();
            $(img).load(function () {
                $(this).hide();
                $('#ipcam').removeClass('loading').append(this);
                $(this).show();
            }).error(function () {
            // notify the user that the image could not be loaded
            }).attr('src', url + randval);    
   }, 1000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});

</script>
</head>
<body id="page">
    <div id="ipcam" class="loading">
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know what I should do to place the new fetched image in the div container, called "ipcam", correctly?

Comment: Since it works, please mark devnull69's answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You `.append()` the image to the `div#ipcam` without removing the previous content. Try this

```
$('#ipcam').removeClass('loading').html("").append(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use setTimeout() instead of setInterval().

setTimeout will ensure the image is updated before any new request is made.

setInterval will make new requests even if old ones haven't finished yet. This can lead to display issues if a request returns in the wrong order. It's also not very efficient, because it will waste the viewer's bandwidth on requests which may never be seen.